# The limit set of decreasing sequence of sets is connected if each of the sets in the sequence is connected and compact.

Tags: limits, compactness, connectedness

Let $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of decreasing sets ($S_{n+1}\subset{}S_{n}$) that are compact and connect. I am trying to show that the limit set $$S=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}S_n$$ is also connected.

I know that $S$is non-empty since each $S_n$ is compact and they're decreasing.

Suppose for a contradiction $S$ is disconnected. Then $S=A\cup{}B$ where $A,B$ are non-empty, disjoint, open subsets of $S$.

I don't know what to do from here, but my intuition tells me a contradiction should work.

Comment: This is almost the same as  the following post and the proof given there works: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776439/x-a-compact-hausdorff-space-and-a-sequence-a-1-supset-a-2-supset-dots-of?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of a nested sequence of nonempty
compact sets is nonempty. *(Proof : If it is empty then there is an open cover of $S$ by the
increasing sequence $\big\{S − S_i\big\}_{i=1}^\infty$
. This must have a finite subcover, so $S_i = ∅$ for some $i$,
which is a contradiction.)*

Now uppose that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty S_i$
is not connected. Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint nonempty closed
sets so that$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty =S_i = A ∪ B$. Find disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ so that $A ⊂ U$ and $B ⊂ V$ .
Put $F_i= S_i − (U ∪ V )$. Then $\{F_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is a nested sequence of compact sets, whose
intersection is empty. Thus $F_i = ∅$ for some $i$. That is, $S_i ⊂ U ∪ V$.
However, $S_i$
intersects both $U$ and $V$ , since $S_i ∩A\neq ∅$ and $S_i ∩B\neq ∅$.Contradiction

Comment: Why are we allowed to take $A,B$ to be closed, I thought for disconnectedness we require $A,B$ to be open.

Comment: That is obvious. See I have edited.

Comment: Why is the intersection of $F_i$'s empty?

Comment: Apologies, I just read your edit. Thank you!

Comment: That's ok and Your welcome